# NOW() of SQL in Slick FRM

Tags: mysql, sql, scala, slick

I am using [Slick FRM](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/introduction.html) to have it generate SQL code and connect to a MySQL server.

I failed to find a way to call `NOW()` function in SQL provided by MySQL server from within Scala code but have to generate a `Datetime` object and call its `now()` method in Scala code which results in obtaining the current time of the server that runs Scala application rather than the server time of the MySQL which would be obtained by calling `NOW()` in SQL code.

Can anyone shed some light ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [User-Defined Features](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/userdefined.html)

In your case something like this should work:

```
val now = SimpleLiteral[java.sql.Date]("NOW")
```

EDIT

According to [GitHub issue](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/928) it is not possible to use user defined functions in other use cases than queries. So it seems it is not a fit for your problem.

In that case I guess you have to use [plain SQL](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/sql.html) for that one.

```
sqlu"""update TAoneBattSysRealtime set updateTime = NOW() where hwid = ${r.hwid}"""
```

Comment: Thanks @thwiegan. I checked the documentation per your refer. Now I have encountered below issue. First I changed a bit of your proposal: Data->Timestamp.  I was using Slick codegen to generate source code hence the object name TAoneBattSysRealtime.
val now = SimpleLiteral[java.sql.Timestamp]("NOW");
TAoneBattSysRealtime.filter(row ⇒ row.hwid === r.hwId).map(x ⇒
x.updateTime).update(now)
The above line yielded a compile error Error:(183, 26) type ismatch;
 found: slick.lifted.Rep[java.sql.Timestamp]
 required: java.sql.Timestamp  Some(now)). I failed to unlift the return type of now().